A person takes 8 minutes to cut a piece of log into 5 pieces. How long would it take to cut it into 10 pieces?
A person takes 8 minutes to cut a piece of log into 5 pieces. How long would it take to cut it into 10 pieces?
One of the solutions which I thought of in the beginning was,
To cut a piece of wood into a pieces, you require (a-1) cuts.
Therefore it takes 8 minutes to saw the log 4 times.
Similarly, it takes x minutes to saw the log 9 times.
Upon solving, we get
8/4 = x/9, x = 18.
But some other solutions which I found on the web solve it as follows:
8 minutes are required to cut the log into 5 pieces.
x minutes are required to cut the log into 10 pieces.
8/5 = x/10, x = 16.
My question is, is the second approach wrong? Why or why not? Shouldn't the answer be 18 rather than 16 on the web?

how long to cut the log into 1 piece?

You're right, the other approach is wrong.

This is a similar mistake to "It takes $70$ orchestra members $70$ minutes to play beethoven's 9th symphony.  How long does it take an orchestra with $140$ members to play beethoven's 9th symphony?"  The bad solution is to say "twice as many people, half as much time"... they are shoehorning in approaches that may indeed work in other scenarios into these without thinking about if it is appropriate.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.


Specifically where on the web does it say 16 minutes? 2. Anyone can make a web page and put all kinds of nonsense on it.


https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/p-a-man-took-3-minutes-to-saw-a-wooden-plank-into-4-pieces-how/ A similar question which has a wrong solution by a reputed website. This is a similar question, but on a few other websites, there's this exact question where they say the answer is 16 minutes.

I'm pretty sure you can cut into 5 pieces with 3 cuts and 10 pieces with 4 cuts if the cuts can intersect.
